# How much content should a <header> container contain?

Tags: html, seo, markup

I was wondering, what is considered to be the right amount of content for the main  tag of Your website?

For example, I have the following structure:

```
<header>
    logo
    navigation
    searchbar
</header>
<main>
    object1
    object2
    object3
    object4
    object5
    object6
</main>
```

SEO-wise , is it a mistake to do the following:

```
<header>
   logo
   navigation
   searchbar
   object1
   object2
   object3
   object4
</header>
<main>
   object5
   object6
</main>
```

Does the Search-engine bots and crawlers scan the semantic (or in my way of thought-visual) structure of the website?

Another example -> If there is just a logo, navigation and a searchbar in the top section of the website that is considered the main  element, is it a bad thing if I place the slider and another section of the website in it?

I hope You guys can understand me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no restriction. As long as content is unique and special keywords it will be fine.

The arrangement does not matters.

Answer (score 2):

it depends on the structure of your website but there is no restriction , the only thing that google knows is the folding page of your website , fine tune the code and contents in the folding page the other things are make the alt tag of the logo.